# How to skip an express sub app for requests that don't accept JSON

Tags: express, middleware

I have two Express sub apps setup. One will serve the backend API and the other will serve my react Single Page App. Both Apps are then mounted in the main app. I would like to only send requests to the apiServer sub app if the incoming request accepts JSON.

Here is what I have so far.

```
const express = require( 'express');

// two express sub apps
const reactServer = require('./reactServer');
const apiServer = require('./apiServer')

const app = express();

// middelware to check for json
const onlyJSON = (req, res, next)=>{
  if(req.headers.accept.indexOf('json') === -1){
    next('route') // this doesn't appear to work
  }else{
   next()
  }
}

app.use('/api', onlyJSON, apiServer);
app.use('/', reactServer);
app.listen(3000);
```

This doesn't work.  Requests that come from a browser are still handled by the apiServer.  The idea is that they should flow to the reactServer. Is this something that can be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make it work if you use [`app.all()`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.all) instead of `app.use()`.

Quick example:

```
let apiRouter   = express.Router();
let reactRouter = express.Router();

const onlyJSON = (req, res, next)=>{
  if(req.headers.accept.indexOf('json') === -1){
    next('route');
  } else{
   next()
  }
}

apiRouter  .use((req, res) => res.send('api'));
reactRouter.use((req, res) => res.send('react'));

app.all('/api*', onlyJSON, apiRouter);
app.all('*',    reactRouter);
```

I think it's because `app.use()` isn't considered a route, so `next('route')` doesn't work.

Comment: This does appear to work. Although I have to use full paths in the sub routers.  like `router.get(/api/test)`. Whereas `app.use()` will let me just use `router.get(api/test)`. But I get it. Now this is really more like "route specific middleware". so `next('route') works.

Answer (score 0):

Excellent question. There really doesn't seem to be a way to do what you want built in to express. In searching through reported issues, however, it turns out at least one other person [also wants that feature](https://github.com/expressjs/express/issues/2241) and actually wrote a [pitstop module](https://github.com/ChiperSoft/pitstopjs) that looks like it does what you need:

```
const pitstop = require('pitstop');

const apiIfJson = pitstop()
  .condition((req, res, next) => next(req.headers.accept.indexOf('json') !== -1))
  .use(apiServer);

app
  .use('/api', apiIfJson)
  .use('/', reactServer)
  .listen(3000);
```